# created files are deleted on glassfish shutdown

Tags: java, primefaces, glassfish, itext

I developing web application using glassfish 4.0 and primefaces 4.0. application creates pdf (using Itext) , convert it to small jpeg files and saving in on disk. Unfortunately during server shutdown all these files are deleted.

Do you know what is the reason for this deletion and how to turn in off?

Regards

Comment: Where are you writing them to? Maybe this is some intention of Glassfish to cleanup...

Comment: I writing in to glassfish domain docroot folder, I'am using these files as thumbs to pdf document (pdf's are also deleted)

Comment: You have to store files out side your context of web application.

Comment: hmm, then can you tell me where I should store them, I thought, that docroot folder is also for that purpose? and is that really the reason? when I uploading files and saving them in same place these files are not removed